# Should I validate an embedded timestamp in a PAdES signature when doing signature verification?

Tags: pdf, timestamp, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm trying to understand if and how I should validate a PAdES signature with an embedded timestamp.
This embedded timestamp is obtained from a timestamp authority (TSA).

If the signature includes crl file or ocsp response, we should generally first validate the chain of certificates from the signature is not expired nor revoked at the date corresponding to this timestamp.

As the timestamp from a TSA is also signed, I'm trying to figure out if I should also validate the chain of certificates of this timestamp and how to validate it ?

With Bouncy Castle API, it's quite easy to validate a timestamp through the following code

`TimeStampToken.validate((SignerInformationVerifier paramSignerInformationVerifier))`

However this method doesn't verify if the chain of certificates is not expired nor revoked.
Moreover as the embedded timestamp do not contain any crl file nor ocsp response, it is not possible to validate the chain of certificates at the date the timestamp has been embedded in the signature.

So how could we possibly validate a PAdES signature if we can't fully validate the chain of certificates of the TSA at the date corresponding to the embedded timestamp?

Comment: When doing PAdES signing you need to collect all relevant OCSP responses and CRLs and put them to the list. I don't know about bouncycastle, but in SecureBlackbox this is dealt with automatically.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your quick reply... However I'm not talking about ocsp response or crl file from certificates involved directly in the signature.

Comment: Here I'm talking about signature timestamp from a TSA. As far as I know in the creation of this timestamp, the certificate of the TSA is also involved. But when a TSA timestamp is created and embedded in a PAdES signature there is no mechanism to embedded crl file nor ocsp response for this timestamp. Only the TSA certificate path could be optionally embedded with the timestamp. As a consequence, there is no way to validate/verify this certificate at the time corresponding to the timestamp (in particular, revocation of the certificate).

Comment: I understood you. You can include OCSP and CRLs related to the timestamp to PAdES signature.

Comment: Great ! I'd really like to understand how to do this with iText and Bouncy Castle. As a matter of fact, when a timestamp is added by iText, I can't find any crl file nor ocsp response for the timestamp certificate. So I will probably ask a more specific question to the iText community. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The last tine I looked iText did not include validation information for embedded time stamps. With a little work, though, you could add that functionality. Furthermore, btw, OCSP responses and CRLs also are signed. For a full blown verification, those signatures also have to be properly verified.