# How to embedded CRL/OCSP revocation information for PAdES signature timestamp with iText?

Tags: validation, timestamp, itext, signature

This question is linked to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105496/should-i-validate-an-embedded-timestamp-in-a-pades-signature-when-doing-signatur).

As I would like to fully validate the timestamp added to a PAdES signature (expiration and revocation), I need also to add to the signature the crl file or the ocsp response of the TSA certificate grabbed at the creation of the timestamp.

As far as I understand, iText 5.4.1 doesn't seem to provide this feature.
In particular through

- com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClientBouncyCastle, and
- com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding CRLs, you can add a CrlClient that gets the CRL for the TSA Certificate to the CrlList passed to MakeSignature.

Regarding the OCSP response: you're right. It seems that we don't have a means to do this, other then when creating a Document-Level Timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the clarification... So do you mean that as soon as we add a DSS and a Document-Level Timestamp, it is no more necessary to validate CRLs or OCSP response embedded in the signature nor certificate chain involved in the signature because these will be also added in the DSS. So DSS and Document-Level Timestamp validation is enough to verify the integrity of the signature and also the validity of the signature ?

Comment: The DSS is a means to add more recent Verification-related information such as CRLs, OCSP,... for all certificates in the certificate chain of the signing certificate and the timestamping certificate. That's not the same as saying 'that info is enough to verify the validity of the signature'. You need to check the latest DSS first, then the one before that, etc... and finally check the CRLs, OCSPs,... inside the signature. In short: you need to check them all. (See the definition in PAdES-4.)

Comment: In PAdES-4 (ETSI TS 102 778-4 V1.1.2), the components to validate the signature are 
1) Validation data referenced in VRI component in DSS. 
2) Validation data referenced in DSS. 
3) Validation data embedded in the signature (e.g. OCSP data see part 2 [i.4], clause 4.4). 
4) Validation data referenced in from the local repository. 
5) Validation data referenced in retrieved from an on-line source. 

So what's the purpose to add and validate OSCP & CRLs in part 2, if we add and validate OSCP & CRLs in part-4 through DSS and Document-Level Timestamp ? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: Suppose I need to sign a document with a promise to you. In that case, I may have interest in omitting OSCP and CRL info, so that I can afterwards claim "I didn't sign this; it's a forgery." That's why you'll add a DSS + Document-Level Timestamp upon receiving the document. If you all certificates verify, you're sure that the document is OK. I hope this simple example proves that it's not always redundant.

Comment: I fully understand this use case... however, do we have to add OCSP and CRL info (part 2) and adding again the same information in DSS (part-4) if all these operations are executed at the same time ? In that specific case, does adding DSS and Document-Level Timestamp enough ? Sorry but I'm a bit confused when and where should I add and validate which information (signature and document integrity, certificate expiration and revocation, LTV validation) depending on the use case. I would love to see this topic added to your very well written white paper 'Digital signatures for PDF document'.

Comment: Adding a DSS and a Document-Level Timestamp is something that usually isn't done at the moment of signing. It's usually done much later: to add missing Certificates, OCSPs, CRLs,... To add a signature with a better hashing and/or encryption algorithm,...

Comment: @bgillis Adding OCSP/CRL information as per PAdES-2 is essentially good old PDF-1-style. Thus, if you want to supply the information in a format understood by not PAdES-4-enabled viewers, include them there. The backdraw is that those information are from **before** the actual time of signing. If you want to have information positively showing that the certificates were valid even at the time of signing, definitively use the PAdES-4 way. If you want to add validation information a posteriori, you have to use PAdES-4 style.