# BouncyCastle Error "Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerOctetString'

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle, signing

Woking with BouncyCastle and trying to casting `Asn1Object` to `DerOctetString`

`DerOctetString dosCrlDP = (DerOctetString)derObjCrlDP;`

Getting the casting error: **"Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerOctetString'."**

The full code is given below

```
public List<string> getCrlDistributionPoints(Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert)
{
    byte[] crldpExt = cert.GetExtensionValue(X509Extensions.CrlDistributionPoints.Id).GetOctets();
    if ((crldpExt == null))
    {
        List<string> emptyList;
        return emptyList;
    }

    Asn1InputStream oAsnInStream = null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */;
    Asn1InputStream oAsnInStream2 = null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */;
    List<string> crlUrls;
    try
    {
        oAsnInStream = new Asn1InputStream(new MemoryStream(crldpExt));
        Asn1Object derObjCrlDP = oAsnInStream.ReadObject;
        //Getting the casting error.
        DerOctetString dosCrlDP = (DerOctetString)derObjCrlDP;
        byte[] crldpExtOctets = dosCrlDP.GetOctets;
        oAsnInStream2 = new Asn1InputStream(new MemoryStream(crldpExtOctets));
        Asn1Object derObj2 = oAsnInStream2.ReadObject;
        CrlDistPoint distPoint = CrlDistPoint.GetInstance(derObj2);
        foreach (DistributionPoint dp in distPoint.GetDistributionPoints)
        {
            DistributionPointName dpn = dp.DistributionPointName;
            // Look for URIs in fullName
            if ((!(dpn) == null))
            {
                if (dpn.GetType.Name == DistributionPointName.FullName)
                {
                    GeneralName[] genNames = GeneralNames.GetInstance(dpn.Name).GetNames;
                    // Look for an URI
                    int j = 0;
                    while ((j < genNames.Length))
                    {
                        if ((genNames[j].TagNo == GeneralName.UniformResourceIdentifier))
                        {
                            string url = DerIA5String.GetInstance(genNames[j].Name).GetString;
                            crlUrls.Add(url);
                        }

                        j = (j + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
    }

    return crlUrls;
}
```

I have no idea how to deal with it.

Please share ideas, suggestions, and working code. or any alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I know about the casting types. I need a solution to this particular type of error. What to change with code that converts the `Asn1Object` to `DerOctetString`? Have you any idea?

Comment: Your `oAsnInStream.ReadObject` returns one type, you try to cast it to a variable of another. As there is no standard casting, you should create your own.

Comment: You don't have "code that converts the Asn1Object to DerOctetString". You have to create it.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Check this link and see how casting works in this java code:  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330079/18803035](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330079/18803035) Please help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say

> Check this link and see how casting works in this java code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330079/18803035

The difference between that code and yours is that in the Java code there is

```java
final byte[] crldpExt = cert.getExtensionValue(X509Extension.cRLDistributionPoints.getId());
```

while in your C# code you have

```c#
byte[] crldpExt = cert.GetExtensionValue(X509Extensions.CrlDistributionPoints.Id).GetOctets();
```

Apparently, the Java `cert.getExtensionValue` returns a `byte[]` while the C# `cert.GetExtensionValue` returns something with a `GetOctets()` method. Looking into the (open source!!) code of .NET BouncyCastle one sees that the C# version actually returns an `Asn1OctetString` object of which you call that `GetOctets()` method.

Thus, while the Java code first has to put the retrieved `byte[]` into an `ASN1InputStream` and call `readObject()` to get an `...OctetString` object, the C# code already has that `...OctetString` object. Furthermore, your call of `GetOctets()` retrieves the content contained in the octet string, not an encoding of that full octet string object anymore.

In the code lines quoted above, therefore, the C# code already is one step ahead of the Java code in the process of unwrapping the information. So you have to remove the extra code required for that step in Java.

In other words, as a quick fix replace

```c#
oAsnInStream = new Asn1InputStream(new MemoryStream(crldpExt));
Asn1Object derObjCrlDP = oAsnInStream.ReadObject;
//Getting the casting error.
DerOctetString dosCrlDP = (DerOctetString)derObjCrlDP;
byte[] crldpExtOctets = dosCrlDP.GetOctets;
```

by

```c#
byte[] crldpExtOctets = crldpExt;
```

Beware, I did not check whether there are similar differences in the following code, too, where you'd have to consider what you actually do.

---

As a side note, there not only are certain differences between the Java and the .NET version of BouncyCastle; actually there are certain breaking changes between arbitrary BouncyCastle versions even though the version numbers may differ only in the minor position. Thus, whenever re-using BouncyCastle code you find somewhere, be prepared to have to look up and compare the BouncyCastle APIs used by your source and by you unless you're using the exactly identical version.